# how to get result if 2nd field is empty in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

if i use this link it is working fine
search.php?search=ali&city=dubai&submit=Search

but if i use this no result found 
search.php?search=ali&city=0&submit=Search

I have three rows in data table

- 1st is name
- 2nd is city
- 3rd is date

if i search name with city it is showing result but
when i search only name then no result found
i want both type of result.

how can i fix this isuuse
thanks in advance

```
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE $construct  AND  city='$city' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: RTM on `WHERE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html and add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and you will see the syntax error you are probably making, since we have NO idea what your `$construct` does.

Comment: Is it really worth mentioning the [deprecated 'thing' about mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and [sql injection vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)? What do you think @Fred-ii-? I see you around php a lot and this uses keep coming. I don't know if I should keep repeating myself about this...

Comment: Your questions is **unanswerable** in its present state and for many reasons. Which MySQL API used to connect with, where those variables are assigned as, and the list goes on. ***"You"*** have to learn how to ***"debug"*** your code; that isn't our job, it's yours.

Comment: @FirstOne Given the OP's track record and questions asked, I wouldn't waste my breath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Remove the City condition where clause as show below.

```
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE $construct 
ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

Then set the value of $construct according to data availability.

If only "Name" is available in query string, then set $construct as `Name=$search`

if both name and city is available, then set $construct as `Name=$search` and `city=$city`

Comment: I'll repost my comment I left in the "now deleted answer": I wouldn't move so fast with this. Not without knowing what their `$construct` does exactly, and wasn't posted.